# Using the Poisson distribution on two dependent events?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

**Problem**:
Suppose the number of cars passing a road follows Poisson distribution with average 5 cars per minute. Also suppose the percent of red cars follows Poisson distribution with average 20% cars being red.

Then how would you answer something like: what is the probability of at least 50% of the cars passing the road in 10 minutes are red?

**Approach**:
I can do this problem brute force:

1. Average number of cars expected to see in 10 minutes is 50 cars.
2. Then from there calculate probability of seeing 1 car, 2 cars, all the way up to a large number of cars -until probability ends up being close to 0.
3. Then for X given number of cars, determine the probability >50% are red. Multiple this probability by the probability of seeing X number of cars. Repeat this for all number of cars and add up the probabilities.

Is there a faster / more methodical way of answering this question?

Comment: The percentage of red cars does not follow a Poisson distribution though (marginally) the number of red cars might. Perhaps each car has a $20\%$ chance of being red, independently of the colours of the other cars. You also seem to switch between $\ge 50\%$ and $\gt 80\%$.  But (after dealing with those points) your suggested approach seems fairly reasonable and can be done quickly with a computer.

Comment: Thanks I might go with this approach then. Also corrected typo regarding 50% and 80%.